# Why does selects-behaviour differ when trying to read and write sockets?

Tags: c++, c, http, sockets, select

Lets say we have a client file-descriptor accepted with accept()

```cpp
client_socket = accept(_socket, (sockaddr *)&client_addr, &len)
```

We now set this file-descriptor in a read and write fd_set:

```cpp
fd_set readfds;
fd_set writefds;

//zero them
FD_ZERO(readfds);
FD_ZERO(writefds);

//set the client_socket
FD_SET(client_socket, &readfds);
FD_SET(client_socket, &writefds);
```

now we use select the to check if the socket is readable or writable:

```cpp
select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfs, &writefds, NULL, NULL)
```

We now check if we can read first and read all bytes from it.

```cpp
if (FD_ISSET(client_socket, &readfds) {
    read(client_socket, &buf, 4096);
}
//assume that buf is big enough and that read returns less than 4096
```

In the next loop we reset the fd_sets just like before.
Now select will allow us to write our response to the client:

```cpp
if (FD_ISSET(client_socket, &readfds) {
    write(client_socket, &buf, len(buf));
}
```

Till here everything works fine but now the weird behaviour occurs.
Lets assume that our client told us to keep the connection alive, in that
case we would set the fd_set the same way as before like this:

```cpp
//zero them
FD_ZERO(readfds);
FD_ZERO(writefds);

//set the client_socket
FD_SET(client_socket, &readfds);
FD_SET(client_socket, &writefds);
// reading not allowed
```

When using select now it will allow us to write again but it won't allow to read from the client_socket.
BUT if we change the setting of the writefds to zero it will allows us to read, although we did not change anything in the readfds.

```cpp
//zero them
FD_ZERO(readfds);
FD_ZERO(writefds);

//set the client_socket
FD_SET(client_socket, &readfds);
//FD_SET(client_socket, &writefds); -> don't set the file-descriptors for write
// now reading is allowed
```

Can someone explain me if this is the correct behaviour of select or if this is my fault maybe in other parts of the code that I didn't show (way too complex).
For me it seems like the behaviour of select is random when setting both sets (writing and reading).
I know that there is a way around this by keeping a kind of state to decide if we want to set the reading-file-descriptors or the writing-file-descriptors, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Typo? Now select will allow us to write our response to the client: `if (FD_ISSET(client_socket, &readfds)`?

Comment: `select` does not guarantee that it sets the socket in the both sets readfds and writefds.

Comment: sorry I meant FD_ISSET(client_socktes , writefds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `select()` is to *not return until there is something for your program to do*.  That way your program can sleep inside `select()` until I/O is ready, wake up immediately to do the I/O, and then go back to sleep as quickly as possible afterwards.

So the question is, how does `select()` know when to return?  The answer is, you have to tell it what should cause it to return, by calling `FD_SET()` in the appropriate ways.

Usually you will want `select()` to return when data is ready-for-read on any of your sockets (so you can read the newly-arrived data), so you should usually call `FD_SET(mySock, &readFD)` on all of your sockets.

`FD_SET(mySock, &writeFD)` is a bit more nuanced.  It tells `select()` to return when the socket has buffer-space available to write output bytes to.  However, in many cases you **don't** want `select()` to return when a socket has buffer-space available, simply because you don't currently have any data that you want to write to the socket anyway.  In that scenario, if you always call `FD_SET(mySocket, &writeFD)` then `select()` will keep returning immediately even though you don't have any task you want to perform, and that will cause your program to use up lots of CPU cycles for no good purpose.

So the only time you should call `FD_SET(mySocket, &writeFD)` is if you know that you want to write some data to that socket ASAP.

In your program, what is likely happening is that `FD_SET(mySocket, &writeFD)` is causing `select()` to return immediately (because `mySocket` currently has buffer-space available to write to), and then your program is (mistakenly) assuming that because `select()` has returned, the socket is ready-for-read, only to find out that it isn't.  In the case where you've commented out the `FD_SET(mySocket, &writeFD)`, OTOH, `select()` doesn't return until the socket is ready-for-read, and so you get the behavior you expect when you call `FD_ISSET(mySocket, &readFD)`.

Comment: "*So the only time you should call `FD_SET(mySocket, &writeFD)` is if you know that you want to write some data to that socket ASAP*" - more accurately, you should only set `writeFD` for the socket when a previous `write()`/`send()` failed with an `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` error. Then you would wait for the socket to become writable (clear up some buffer space) before you re-attempt the failed send again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is one approach but it's not the only way to do it.  For example, I sometimes have my outgoing-data stored in the form of a hashmap of C++ objects, that I serialize on-demand (i.e. only when I know there is buffer-space available to receive at least some of the serialized bytes).  In that case I `FD_SET(mySocket, &writeFD)` whenever I have more serialized bytes to send *or* my table of C++ objects is non-empty, and when the socket selects as ready-for-write I serialize the contents of the table into a byte-buffer and send as much of it as the socket will accept.